# How to make child scrollable instead of resizing parent with CSS?

Tags: css

I have an issue I'm trying to figure out, but can't figure out. There are multiple grids involved so I'm sure the issue has to do with a CSS rule I just don't fully understand.

What I'm trying to do is create a "module" `.module` which is set in size, and if the contents of the `.list` inside that module is too long, there should be a vertical scrollbar inside the module. Essentially, the whole page should not resize because of a module's list being too long. Scrollbars should appear for each individual `.module .list` if needed.

What am I doing wrong? Right now the entire page resizes, and that is not the intended end result. Is there something i'm missing? Any explanations would be helpful so I can learn from this for future projects.

For visual people, this image shows what the end result should look like. Only the elements in the red circle should be scrollable, everything else should stay set in size.

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 65px);
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 96px 30px 1fr 60px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "title"
      "breadcrumb"
      "modules"
      "bottombar"}


  /* --------[TITLE FEATURE]-------- */
  #title {
    grid-area: title;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #484848;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  #breadcrumb {
    grid-area: breadcrumb;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 20px;}

  #breadcrumb ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;}
    #breadcrumb li {display: inline}

  #breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '▸';
    margin: 0px 10px;}

  #breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #581F98;
    font-weight: 800}


  /* --------[MODULES]-------- */
  #modules {
    grid-area: modules;
    padding: 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px 40px;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "graph present absent";}

  .module {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #CECECE}
    .module.clickable:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.03);
      background-color: #D4BBF1}

  .module.graph {grid-area: graph}
  .module.present {grid-area: present}
  .module.absent {grid-area: absent}

  .module .title {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #484848;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  .module .list {overflow: auto;}

  .module .list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;}

  .module .list li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

  .module .list li img {
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    clip-path: circle();}


  /* --------[BOTTOMBAR]-------- */
  #bottombar {
    grid-area: bottombar;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid darkgray;}

    #bottombar input {
      padding: 6px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      border: 1px solid gray}

    #bottombar .button { /* <- Customizes the global button design */
      padding: 8px 24px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 26px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Statistics </title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id='title'>✋ Attendance</div><div id='breadcrumb'>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='?'>Stats</a></li>
              <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Attendance</a></li>
              <li>Overview</li>
            </ul>
          </div><div id='modules'>
            <div class='module graph'></div>
            <div class='module present'>
              <div class='title'>✔ Present</div>
              <div class='list'>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='module absent'>
              <div class='title'>✘ Absent</div>
            </div>
          </div>      <div id='bottombar'>
              </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 65px);
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 96px 30px 1fr 60px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "title"
      "breadcrumb"
      "modules"
      "bottombar"}


  /* --------[TITLE FEATURE]-------- */
  #title {
    grid-area: title;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #484848;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  #breadcrumb {
    grid-area: breadcrumb;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 20px;}

  #breadcrumb ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;}
    #breadcrumb li {display: inline}

  #breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '▸';
    margin: 0px 10px;}

  #breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #581F98;
    font-weight: 800}


  /* --------[MODULES]-------- */
  #modules {
    grid-area: modules;
    padding: 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px 40px;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "graph present absent";}

  .module {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #CECECE}
    .module.clickable:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.03);
      background-color: #D4BBF1}

  .module.graph {grid-area: graph}
  .module.present {grid-area: present; height: 40%; overflow: scroll;}
  .module.absent {grid-area: absent; height: 40%; overflow: scroll;}

  .module .title {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #484848;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  .module .list {overflow: auto;}

  .module .list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;}

  .module .list li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

  .module .list li img {
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    clip-path: circle();}


  /* --------[BOTTOMBAR]-------- */
  #bottombar {
    grid-area: bottombar;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid darkgray;}

    #bottombar input {
      padding: 6px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      border: 1px solid gray}

    #bottombar .button { /* <- Customizes the global button design */
      padding: 8px 24px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 26px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Statistics </title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id='title'>✋ Attendance</div><div id='breadcrumb'>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='?'>Stats</a></li>
              <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Attendance</a></li>
              <li>Overview</li>
            </ul>
          </div><div id='modules'>
            <div class='module graph'></div>
            <div class='module present'>
              <div class='title'>✔ Present</div>
              <div class='list'>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
                    <span>Test Child</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='module absent'>
              <div class='title'>✘ Absent</div>
            </div>
          </div>      <div id='bottombar'>
              </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The only change is that

```css
  .module.present {grid-area: present}
  .module.absent {grid-area: absent}
```

became

```css
  .module.present {grid-area: present; height: 40%; overflow: scroll;}
  .module.absent {grid-area: absent; height: 40%; overflow: scroll;}
```

You can change the height to whatever you need.